# Infinite summation of sinusoidal functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Please help me in solving the following summation or possibly point me in the correct direction

> $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2nx}{n^2} , \quad \quad  0\leq x\leq \pi$

Thank You

Comment: The series converges absolutely for any $\;x\in\Bbb R\;$ ...Is this what you want to know?

Comment: @DonAntonio I have edited the question to include the domain for $x$. I want to know if this reduces to a closed form expression.

Comment: @SrimayaPadhi I'm afraid this is a hopeless quest. I doubt a lot whether there is a closed fomr with only elementary functions for this thing. As already comments, some obscure beasts may appear here and there ,as polylogarithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $$\sin^{2}\left(z\right)=1-\cos^{2}\left(z\right)=\frac{1-\cos\left(2z\right)}{2}
 $$ and $$\cos\left(2z\right)=\frac{e^{2iz}+e^{-2iz}}{2}
 $$ we get $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\sin^{2}\left(nx\right)}{n^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{e^{2inx}}{n^{2}}-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{e^{-2inx}}{n^{2}}
 $$ and recalling [the definition of the Polylogarithm function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html) we have $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\sin^{2}\left(nx\right)}{n^{2}}=\frac{\pi^{2}}{12}-\frac{1}{4}\textrm{Li}_{2}\left(e^{2ix}\right)-\frac{1}{4}\textrm{Li}_{2}\left(e^{-2ix}\right).$$

Answer (score -1):

Maple gives the following answer for your sum
$$-1/4\,{\it polylog} \left( 2,{{\rm e}^{2\,ix}} \right) +1/12\,{\pi}^{2
}-1/4\,{\it polylog} \left( 2,{{\rm e}^{-2\,ix}} \right) 
$$
I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I am looking for an analytical way to solve it.

Comment: i think that is no such way